# How To Call XML POST API

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I need to call an API with POST arguments, for example:

- URL = http://localhost/myAPI/
- ARGS = options=blue&type=car

I've had a look at XDocument but not sure how to send params in the request. I'm also not sure how I would call asynchronously, and even if I should or if it's better/easier to run in another thread.

I'd be calling this from my windows based C# application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use one of the [Upload methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.uploadstring.aspx) of [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tt0f69eh.aspx).

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
string response = client.UploadString(
                  "http://localhost/myAPI/?options=blue&type=car", 
                  "POST data");
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, this helped a lot. I also found that I needed to set client.Headers as well.. Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

Answer (score 1):

## in asp .NET

```
var client = new RestClient("www.api.url");
client.Timeout = -1;
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("id", "givenid");
request.AddHeader("HASH", "generatedHash");
request.AddParameter("text/plain", "fullxml or body",  ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
```

## In HTTP

```
POST /api/somename/1.1
Host: google.com
id: merchantid
HASH: generatedshah
<node1><element>Individual</element></node1>
```

## Phython - http.client

```
import http.client
import mimetypes
conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("url")
payload = "<Node><Element>Individual</Element></Node>"
headers = {
  'id': 'givenid',
  'HASH': 'generatedhash'
}
conn.request("POST", "/api/blacklist/verify", payload, headers)
res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()
print(data.decode("utf-8"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Call it from where?  Javascript?  If so you can use JQuery:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

```
$.post('http://localhost/myAPI/', { options: "blue", type="car"}, function(data) {
  $('.result').html(data);
});
```

data will contain the result of your post.

If from server-side you can use HttpWebRequest and write to it's stream with your params.

```
// Create a request using a URL that can receive a post. 
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create ("http://localhost/myAPI/");
        // Set the Method property of the request to POST.
        request.Method = "POST";
        // Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.
        string postData = "options=blue&type=car";
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (postData);
        // Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        // Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        // Get the request stream.
        Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream ();
        // Write the data to the request stream.
        dataStream.Write (byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        // Close the Stream object.
        dataStream.Close ();
        // Get the response.
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse ();
        // Display the status.
        Console.WriteLine (((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
        // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
        dataStream = response.GetResponseStream ();
        // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (dataStream);
        // Read the content.
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd ();
        // Display the content.
        Console.WriteLine (responseFromServer);
        // Clean up the streams.
        reader.Close ();
        dataStream.Close ();
        response.Close ();
```

Comment: From Question: `I'd be calling this from my windows based C# application.`

Answer (score 0):

To throw another option into the ring, you may want to consider using the `PostAsync` method of `HttpClient` in .NET 4.5.  An admittedly untested stab:

```
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        var task = client.PostAsync(string.Format("{0}{1}", "http://localhost/myAPI", "?options=blue&type=car"), null);
        Car car = task.ContinueWith(
            t =>
            {
                return t.Result.Content.ReadAsAsync<Car>();
            }).Unwrap().Result;
```